# ¿Que opción de la etiqueta video de html5 es para enfocar y no dejar la camara en modo selfie?

Tags: html5, programación-móvil, qrcode, qr

Actualmente utilizo una etiqueta de video para leer codigo QR:

```
 <video id="preview" width="390" height="332"></video>
```

Pero el problema es que me activa la camara en modo selfie. Lo que deseo es que con el celular, enfoque con la camara en modo normal, y no verme yo en el video.

Me gustaría saber si la etiqueta video tiene alguna opción para regalarlo.
¿Se entiende la pregunta?

Información adicional: Para leer codigo QR utilizo la librería instascan.min.js

https://github.com/schmich/instascan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
   document.write("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(function(devices) {
    devices.forEach(function(device) {
      console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
        " id = " + device.deviceId);
        #return device.deviceId
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + error.message);
  });
```

un ejemplo:
https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

github project:
https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/getusermedia/sources/js/main.js

Answer (score 1):

La propia librería [te da la solución](https://github.com/schmich/instascan#instascancameragetcameras):

> ```
> Instascan.Camera.getCameras()
> ```
>
> Enumerate available video devices.
>   Returns promise.
>
> ```
> .then(function (cameras) { ... }) Called when cameras are available.
> ```
>
> cameras: Array of Instascan.Camera instances available for use.

Por tanto, tras crear una instancia con

```
new Instascan.Scanner(...);
```

Puedes buscar las cámaras y elegir la que quieras:

```
scanner.start(camera);
```

En su ejemplo lo que pasa es que usa la primera cámara que se encuentra (cameras[0]):

```
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
        console.log(content);
      });
      Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
```

Pero nada te impide coger la lista de cámaras, que son objetos de la forma:

```
{
  id: <id_de_la_camara>,
  name: '<nombre de la camara>'
}
```

Y montar un select para que el usuario elija.

Comment: gracias por responder. Haber si entendí, si cambio de cameras[0] a cameras[1] activaría la otra cámara y eso podría resultar.
Y lo que me recomiendas, es hacer una combobox o <select .. que tenga la opción de cambiar la cámara. Siendo así, con la opción : {
  id: <id_de_la_camara>,
  name: '<nombre de la camara>'
} podrías dar un ejemplo de donde iría, en que parte sería llamado, y cuando se le enviaría los parámetros?

Answer (score 0):

yo lo he realizado de la siguiente manera y me funciona a la perfección.
Espero poder ayudarte:

```
<video id="preview" width="950" height="1300"></video>

    <script>
        let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner(
            {
                video: document.getElementById('preview'), mirror: false
            }
        );
        scanner.addListener('scan', function(content) {
            window.open(''+ content);
        });
        Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(cameras => 
        {
            if(cameras.length > 0){
                scanner.start(cameras[1]);
            } else {
                console.error("No se ha detectado Camara");
            }
        });
    </script>
```